# Python multithreading local or not?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am new to Python and am making this game which I want other people to be able to connect to; I looked into multi-threading but couldn't find whether this is local host only or if people are able to join from their own location that could be miles away?

Comment: this question doesn't make much sense, but no, multithreading will not help you. maybe you could show us the part of the documentation that led you to believe you could use it for networking and we can explain, what you misunderstood?